# How can I make the float variable to take affect also in the Update?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to make the variable lightenAmount to be affect the changes to apply the changes in the Update ?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class RawImagePixelsChange : MonoBehaviour
{
    RawImage myImage;
    public Texture2D origTex;
    public Texture2D newTex;

    [Range(-1, 1)]
    public float lightenAmount = 0.1f;

    Color[] pixels;

    void Start()
    {
        var texture = GetComponent<RawImage>().texture;
        origTex = texture as Texture2D;

        myImage = GetComponent<RawImage>();

        if (texture != null && origTex != null)
        {
            pixels = origTex.GetPixels();

            newTex = new Texture2D(origTex.width, origTex.height);

            newTex.SetPixels(pixels);
            newTex.Apply();
            myImage.texture = newTex;
        }
    }

    public void modifyPixels(float lightenAmount) // Press "P" to change pixel colors by lightenAmount
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i++)
        {
            pixels[i].r += lightenAmount;
            if (pixels[i].r > 1) pixels[i].r = 1;
            if (pixels[i].r < 0) pixels[i].r = 0;
            pixels[i].g += lightenAmount;
            if (pixels[i].g > 1) pixels[i].g = 1;
            if (pixels[i].g < 0) pixels[i].g = 0;
            pixels[i].b += lightenAmount;
            if (pixels[i].b > 1) pixels[i].b = 1;
            if (pixels[i].b < 0) pixels[i].b = 0;
        }
        newTex.SetPixels(pixels);
        newTex.Apply();
    }
    public void restorePixels()
    {
        pixels = origTex.GetPixels();
        newTex.SetPixels(pixels);
        newTex.Apply();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
        {
            modifyPixels(lightenAmount);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O))
        {
            restorePixels();
        }
    }
}
```

I want that when I change the variable lightenAmount value in run time to take affect of it also in the Update. Now it's only affects the changes when starting the game.

I'm using the variable value later in other script and it's not affecting the changes.

I'm trying to use this variable value in this script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MouseHover : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RawImagePixelsChange rawImagePixelsChange;
    public static string savedGameFName;
    public static string folder;
    public static bool loadingwithfolder = false;

    private bool loadGame = false;
    // Reference the according RawImage here via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private RawImage rawImage;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!rawImage) rawImage = GetComponent<RawImage>();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        
    }

    public void OnHover()
    {
        rawImagePixelsChange.modifyPixels(rawImagePixelsChange.lightenAmount);
        PlaySoundEffect();
        loadGame = true;
    }
    public void OnHoverExit()
    {
        rawImagePixelsChange.restorePixels();
        loadGame = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (loadGame)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                var name = transform.gameObject.GetComponent<RawImageInfo>().FolderAndFileName;
                int index = name.IndexOf(".png");
                string res = name.Substring(index);
                string res1 = name.Substring(0, name.Length - (name.Length - index));
                string res2 = res1 + ".savegame.txt";
                savedGameFName = res2;//@"D:\Unity Projects\The Kid From Space Backup_001\Assets\save_//res2//savegame.txt";
                
                
                loadingwithfolder = true;
                folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(savedGameFName);
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void PlaySoundEffect()
    {
        transform.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
    }
}
```

In this line :

```
rawImagePixelsChange.modifyPixels(rawImagePixelsChange.lightenAmount);
```

Comment: Maybe add "myImage.texture = newTex;" in the Modify Pixels function?

Comment: Yeah nothing is jumping out at me about the `lightenAmount` variable itself, I think it might have something to do with the pixel editing itself. OP, try to use the debugger to confirm if the lightenAmount variable is changing or not at runtime. Or you can just put `Debug.Log(lightenAmount);` at the beginning of modifypixels to see if it's changing when you change it in the inspector

Comment: The solution is to create my own custom slider.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to create my own custom slider. The reason for creating a custom slider is because the Range attribute should not be working at run time. The easiest way is to create a custom slider.

In the first script I removed the Range attribute :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class RawImagePixelsChange : MonoBehaviour
{
    RawImage myImage;

    public Texture2D origTex;
    public Texture2D newTex;

    public float lightenAmount = 0.1f;

    Color[] pixels;

    void Start()
    {
        var texture = GetComponent<RawImage>().texture;
        origTex = texture as Texture2D;

        myImage = GetComponent<RawImage>();

        if (texture != null && origTex != null)
        {
            pixels = origTex.GetPixels();

            newTex = new Texture2D(origTex.width, origTex.height);

            newTex.SetPixels(pixels);
            newTex.Apply();
            myImage.texture = newTex;
        }
    }

    public void modifyPixels(float lightenAmount)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i++)
        {
            pixels[i].r += lightenAmount;
            if (pixels[i].r > 1) pixels[i].r = 1;
            if (pixels[i].r < 0) pixels[i].r = 0;
            pixels[i].g += lightenAmount;
            if (pixels[i].g > 1) pixels[i].g = 1;
            if (pixels[i].g < 0) pixels[i].g = 0;
            pixels[i].b += lightenAmount;
            if (pixels[i].b > 1) pixels[i].b = 1;
            if (pixels[i].b < 0) pixels[i].b = 0;
        }
        newTex.SetPixels(pixels);
        newTex.Apply();
    }
    public void restorePixels()
    {
        pixels = origTex.GetPixels();
        newTex.SetPixels(pixels);
        newTex.Apply();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
        {
            modifyPixels(lightenAmount);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O))
        {
            restorePixels();
        }
    }

    public float Amount()
    {
        return lightenAmount;
    }
}
```

Then created a simple small editor script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

[CustomEditor(typeof(RawImagePixelsChange))]
public class CustomSlider : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        RawImagePixelsChange rawimagepixelschange = (RawImagePixelsChange)target;

        rawimagepixelschange.lightenAmount = EditorGUILayout.Slider(
            rawimagepixelschange.lightenAmount, -1f, 1f);
    }
}
```

And now when changing the slider value in run time it's also changing the lightenAmount value and then when the mouse is enter the OnHover it's changing the pixels color according to the slider value.

Working perfect.